# Display option Text from <select> tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-select

I want to get or display de text of the option selected of my `<select>` but the issue is that these  are generated dynamically so I don't know hot to use the selector (jquery) to catch these values

this is my html where the `<select>` can change

```
<div>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCur" value="AutorCu"><label> Autor</label><br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCur" value="EscuelaCu"><label> Escuela</label><br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCur" value="CategoriasCu"><label> Categorias</label><br>
    </li>
</ul>


<div id="searchCu"><select id="AutorCu"><option>Seleccione una opción</option>
<option value="1">foo1</option>
<option value="2">foo2</option>
<option value="3">fooN</option>
</select>
<select id="EscuelaCu"><option>Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Instituto de Artes</option>
    <option value="2">Instituto de Ciencias Basicas e Ingenieria</option>
    <option value="3">Instituto de Ciencias de la Salud</option>
</select>
<select id="CategoriasCu"><option>Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Arte y arquitectura</option>
    <option value="2">Economia y empresa</option>
    <option value="3">Medios de comunicacion</option>
    <option value="4">Ingenieria</option>
</select></div>
<button id="BuscarCu" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>
```

And the JS

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    //Cursos Procedures
    $("input[name=filterCur").click(function () {
        var checkboxes = $("input[name=filterCur]");
        var searchCu=$("#searchCu");
        $.each(checkboxes,function (index, chk) {
            if(chk.checked)
                switch(chk.value){
                    case "AutorCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        searchCu.append($("<select>",{id:chk.value}));
                        listAutores("#"+chk.value);
                        break;
                    case "EscuelaCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        searchCu.append($("<select>",{id:chk.value}));
                        listEscuelas("#"+chk.value);
                        break;
                    case "CategoriasCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        searchCu.append($("<select>",{id:chk.value}));
                        listCategorias("#"+chk.value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //console.log("el valor seleccionado esta mal, torpe");
                }
            else{
                switch(chk.value){
                    case "AutorCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        break;
                    case "EscuelaCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        break;
                    case "CategoriasCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        break;
                    default:
                        //console.log("el valor seleccionado esta mal, torpe");
                }
            }

        })

    });

    $("button#BuscarCu").on("click",function () {
        var siblings = $("#searchCu > select");
        $.each(siblings,function (index, son) {
            //this consolelog, should display the option selected
            **console.log(son.text());**
            //This consolelog, displays the value of the option selected
            console.log(son.value);

        });
    });
});
```

before you ask or answer `listEscuelas(id)` and `listAutores(id)` and `listCategorias(id)` calls an external js with ajax for php that returns the `<option>` for the `id` of the `<select></select>` for example
if you have a `<select id="foo">` and then you call `listEscuelas(id)` for fillup `foo` id should be **`id="#foo"`** and the result will be something like these or other options

```
<select><option value="1">Instituto de Artes</option>
<option value="2">Instituto de Ciencias Basicas e Ingenieria</option>
<option value="3">Instituto de Ciencias de la Salud</option>
```

Comment: **console.log(son.text());**
This is the console log that should display the `<option>` text

Comment: Next time, please try to construct a smaller example of your problem. You have submitted far too much code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Why yours wasn't working

You used:

```
son.text()
```

Although it may be counter intuitive, jQuery gives you a JavaScript DOM object, and not a jQuery object.  So, you can't call the jQuery function `.text()` from a JavaScript object.  To fix this, simply change it to `$(son).text()`.  However, that will grab all text inside the selection and we only want the text of the selected option.  So, I decided to narrow the search using `.find()` and a selector that checks to see if the value is that of the selected value.

### The solution

So, here's my version of it:

```
console.log($(son).find("[value='"+son.value+"']").text());
```

### Applying it to your code

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    //Cursos Procedures
    $("input[name=filterCur").click(function () {
        var checkboxes = $("input[name=filterCur]");
        var searchCu=$("#searchCu");
        $.each(checkboxes,function (index, chk) {
            if(chk.checked)
                switch(chk.value){
                    case "AutorCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        searchCu.append($("<select>",{id:chk.value}));
                        listAutores("#"+chk.value);
                        break;
                    case "EscuelaCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        searchCu.append($("<select>",{id:chk.value}));
                        listEscuelas("#"+chk.value);
                        break;
                    case "CategoriasCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        searchCu.append($("<select>",{id:chk.value}));
                        listCategorias("#"+chk.value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        //console.log("el valor seleccionado esta mal, torpe");
                }
            else{
                switch(chk.value){
                    case "AutorCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        break;
                    case "EscuelaCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        break;
                    case "CategoriasCu":
                        //console.log("has seleccionado "+chk.value);
                        searchCu.find("#"+chk.value).remove();
                        break;
                    default:
                        //console.log("el valor seleccionado esta mal, torpe");
                }
            }

        })

    });

    $("button#BuscarCu").on("click",function () {
        var siblings = $("#searchCu > select");
        $.each(siblings,function (index, son) {
            //this consolelog, should display the option selected
            console.log($(son).find("[value='"+son.value+"']").text());
            //This consolelog, displays the value of the option selected
            console.log(son.value);

        });
    });
});
```

```html
<div>
<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCur" value="AutorCu"><label> Autor</label><br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCur" value="EscuelaCu"><label> Escuela</label><br>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="filterCur" value="CategoriasCu"><label> Categorias</label><br>
    </li>
</ul>


<div id="searchCu"><select id="AutorCu"><option value="-1">Seleccione una opción</option>
<option value="1">foo1</option>
<option value="2">foo2</option>
<option value="3">fooN</option>
</select>
<select id="EscuelaCu"><option value="-1">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Instituto de Artes</option>
    <option value="2">Instituto de Ciencias Basicas e Ingenieria</option>
    <option value="3">Instituto de Ciencias de la Salud</option>
</select>
<select id="CategoriasCu"><option value="-1">Seleccione una opción</option>
    <option value="1">Arte y arquitectura</option>
    <option value="2">Economia y empresa</option>
    <option value="3">Medios de comunicacion</option>
    <option value="4">Ingenieria</option>
</select></div>
<button id="BuscarCu" class="btn btn-default">Buscar</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```